# How to use `pipeline.start(execution_display_name)`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to control the "Name" field that appears in the SageMaker GUI and pass it custom values, determined upon SageMaker Pipeline execution.

[image]

Specifically I would like to use a time-stamp both for the "Name" field and for defining the pathing used to save SageMaker Pipeline artifacts to S3. That is, I would be able to look at the SageMaker list of executions and quickly be able to match it with the corresponding artifacts.

I have been able to change "Name" by going to `run_pipeline.py` and doing

```py
execution = pipeline.start(execution_display_name='my-exec-name')
```

However, I have no idea where I should define a time-stamp such that it can be used here and in `pipeline.py`, eg.

```py
import time
time_stamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S", time.gmtime())
```

such that `time_stamp` can be passed to both `run_pipeline.py` and `pipeline.py`

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution I can live with. The following changes gave me the functionality I needed.

```py
# run_pipeline.py
import time
time_stamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S", time.gmtime())
pipeline = get_pipeline_driver(time_stamp, args.module_name, args.kwargs)
```

```py
# _utils.py
def get_pipeline_driver(time_stamp, module_name, passed_args=None):
    ...
    return _imports.get_pipeline(time_stamp, **kwargs)
```

```py
# pipeline.py
def get_pipeline(
    time_stamp,
    ...
    ):
```